# REST WCF service - differences data input format (JSON/XML)

Tags: c#, json, xml, wcf, rest

maybe this is a dumb question, but I need some help.

I'm using WCF to make a restful service. Users send me data to my methods through http post request.

I have done one method receiving a string representing data in json format. So, I simply parse it and create my object to read.

My dumb question is: how can I set another method to be able to receive data input in XML format? I mean, for json I simply expect a string to parse. For XML?

This is my first time with this issue and I'd like to learn how to do it in a clean way (like the string for json).

Can you help me?

UPDATE:
For example, I have this sample method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Patient/Add", Method = "POST")]
    int AddPatient(Patient patient);
```

I see the input is a custom class... so, I think clients can send me an xml representing this class.. or not? Can I simply manage the input like this?

Comment: I don't know how it works in c#, but typically you rely on media types when you want to specify the accepted formats of a rest service. In your json service you should specify that it consumes 'application/json', while on the other one you'll specify 'application/xml'

Comment: I have done this: [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Erogazioni?retista={codret}&lotto={nLotto}&H={hashedString}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)] for the output format... but for the input? do you some example,also with other languages?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a second method that allows you to receive data in xml format?

Comment: @Zanuff yes, I mean this! :)

Comment: well, in Java you would simply annotate the methods specifying what are the accepted media types : `@POST @Consumes("application/json") public void getDataInJSON(Date automaticallyParsedDate)`. However, there is a library (Jersey) that takes care of marshalling/unmarshalling of data according to the media types you specify. I don't know how it could be done in c#.

Comment: For the Input you can set RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml. Personally I use [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            UriTemplate = "xml")]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I use something like this.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "json")]
    void AddUsefulLinkJson(UsefulLinksWCF.Models.UsefulLink link);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        UriTemplate = "xml")]
    void AddUsefulLinkXml(UsefulLinksWCF.Models.UsefulLink link);
```

So then when you use a client you can request data in json or xml like this:

http://www.something.com/UsefulLinks/rest/xml

or

http://www.something.com/UsefulLinks/rest/json

There is a good article on MSDN regarding format selection starting from NET 4.0:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

When enabled, automatic formatting chooses the best format in which to return the response. It determines the best format by checking the following, in order:

The media types in the request message’s Accept header.

The content-type of the request message.

The default format setting in the operation.

The default format setting in the WebHttpBehavior.

Comment: I was ready to edit my post to write if this can be a right way to do it. So, with this code I manage like a custom class in both case but clients are able to send me the in the format they prefer. A question: if client send me a string representing json, I get it already parsed for the input class, right?

Comment: Yes. The client needs to send the correct format using correct Uri and it'll be deserialized to your class.

Comment: So it is not my work, the wcf does it, well. But.. reading around abuot this requestFormat... I ask now... is this really useful? Or if I write only one poster without specifing the requestFormat.. can I manage both without issues? Or is it better to split it?

Comment: This code was written long time ago. According to msdn, starting from NET 4.0 you can use AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled property to tell WCF to use format based on the request message. More info on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: so, in your opionio, which is the best choice? Another question (last): if I want more UserfulLink in a list, can I simply write void AddUsefulLinkXml(List<UsefulLinksWCF.Models.UsefulLink> link) ?

Comment: If you can use NET 4.0 I would go with automatic format selection. As for the AddUsefulLink method the question is if WCF is smart enough to deserialize Json array into List. Guess it is best to try it for yourself :)

Comment: In output it works... it converts my list to xml/json... so, I hope also in input! ;) thanks!